# SAP HANA SDI ECC Source vs HANA table delta

Tags: hana, sap-erp

In our current system, we have a lot of ECC tables replicated to SAP HANA with SDI (Smart Data Integration). Replication tasks can be real-time or on demand, but sometimes a replication task comes too late and the data in the replicated table is very different from the source table.

What would be the best approach in SAP HANA to check these delta values?

- ERP system uses DB2 database
- DB2LogReaderAdapter is used to read DB2 database tables
- Remote source is created in the Cloud (Virtual table)
- There are about 260 replication tasks
- Replication tasks contain only one object
- Replication tasks are based on virtual tables
- The biggest issue faced right now is latency in the remote source tables (delta values)

Comment: How did you implement the replication? The answer depends on the technique you used

Comment: How many data replication tasks do you have? Do you have many source objects in one task (if yes are they large) or multiple tasks (one-per-object)? Which adapter do you use (which DB is source)? Did you try to monitor your tasks? Any errors? Do you have inconsistencies with realtime or with on-demand tasks? Too little input given, need more info of your landscape and/or your flowgraph

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy/straightforward way to "check" delta values here.
The 260 replication tasks are processed independently from each other; regardless of transactional compounding in the source system.
That means, that if table A and B are updated in the same transaction, but replicated in separate tasks to HANA, the data will be written to HANA in separate transactions. The data in HANA will be lagging behind the source system.

Usually, this difference should only last a relatively short time (maybe a few secs.), but, of course, if you do aggregation queries and want to see *current* valid sums etc. this leads to wrong data.

One way to deal with this is to implement the queries in a way that takes this into account, by e.g. filtering on data that has been changed half an hour ago (or longer), and to exclude newer data.

Note that as the replication via LogReader is de-coupled from the source system's transaction processing, this problem of "lagging data" is built-in conceptionally and cannot be generally avoided.
All one can do is to reduce the extend of the lag and cope with the differences in the upstream processing.

This very issue is one of the reasons for why remote data access is usually preferred over replication for cases like operational reporting. 
And if you do need data-loading (e.g. to avoid additional load on the source system) then a ETL/ELT approach into data stores (DWH/BW-like) makes the situation a lot better structures.

In fact, the current S/4 HANA & BW/4 HANA setups usually use a combination of scheduled data loads and ad-hoc fetching of new data via **operational delta queues** from the source system.

Comment: This answer helps a lot. Thank you for taking the time. So, in your opinion, customized queries would be the way forward to check these delta values?

Answer (score 0):

Lars,
If we need to replicate data from ECC on Oracle to a HANA instance, should we use SLT (because of cluster tables for example) or SDI already covers all functionality SLT provides?
Regards, Chris

Comment: Seems this is a question, not an answer, I think you can put comments under the question itself to clarify the question.